# Как найти input в строке по id и добавить в него value посредством регулярки в PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom

Пока решение такое:

```
$html = str_replace(
"<input id='printed_name' type='text' class='forma_input' required='' style='position: relative;top: -8px;'>", 
"<input id='printed_name' type='text' class='forma_input' required='' style='position: relative;top: -8px;' value='1234'>", $str);
```

Comment: по хорошему id должно быть уникально в файле. Вот и стоит ли городить программу, если можно поменять в тектовом редакторе?

Comment: приходит html, который нужно конвертировать в pdf и при этом заполнить необходимые поля

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно вам лучше использовать класс [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

```
$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>header</title>
 </head> 
 <body>
  <input id='printed_name' type='text' class='forma_input' required='' style='position: relative;top: -8px;'>
 </body> 
</html>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($html);
$el = $doc->getElementById('printed_name');
$el->setAttribute( "value", "1234" );

var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

[Run code](https://3v4l.org/SUuBL)